# Python multiprocessing shared memory: list of lists

Tags: python, multiprocessing, shared-memory

Is it possible to share memory for a list of lists using [`multiprocessing.Array()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#shared-ctypes-objects) or something similar? Also, is it possible to share a more complex object such as a `scipy.sparse.lil_matrix`? How would I go about doing that? Are there any examples for either? This variable doesn't have to be modified, but it consumes a lot of memory (~1GB per process), and I'm hoping shared memory will cut back the memory usage. Or is that incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

In general, no (and Python is especially bad at copy-on-write multiprocessing, because even reading an object means changing its refcount, and that's a write operation).

You could, however, try to work with memory-mapped files. Dump your dataset in one, open it from multiple processes and reap the benefits of your OS's I/O caching.

What are you doing with your dataset?

Comment: Are you referring to mmap? Does this solve the memory problem? Would it be possible to link to a related example to get me started? The dataset is multi-dimensional heuristic calibration data for a scientific model contained in the worker function.

Comment: Yeah, I'm talking about mmap -- the idea is to store your data on your hard drive and rely on your OS's caching to move things in and out of memory. However, it demands that your data be in a format that you can process as a list of bytes, which could be fairly painful if you're dealing with multi-dimensional data.